# Removing a class from an element when other element is being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image][image]I have a sticky navbar that contains 4 divs with class .menu-container. Each one of these divs contains an image, a text and a div with classes .rectangle and .hidden. Basically, my goal is to remove the class .hidden when a specific element of .menu-container is being clicked.
I tried different ways to remove the class. One of them was to add rectangle[el].classList.remove('hidden') but I get undefined and strangely the rectangle appears in the browser, but when I check in the console I get this error 'Uncaught'.
Here's the code to make it clear:

```js
"use strict";

const rectangle = document.querySelectorAll(".rectangle");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu-container').forEach(el =>             
    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
      rectangle.classList.remove('hidden');
      console.log('clicked');
    }
   )
  )
})
```

```css
.sticky {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 0 287px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  background-color: $light--black;
  // align-items: center;
  // align-items: stretch;
  


  .menu-container {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;


      &:hover {
        .text-sticky {
          color: white;
        }
        .icon-coffee--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-coffee--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-capsules--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-capsules--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-mousse--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-mousse--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-machines--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-machines--white {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      @include between(1, 3) {
        position: relative;
        &::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          width: 0.5px;
          right: -3px;
          min-height: 41px;
          background-color: $white;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
      }

      .icon-coffee {
        width: 44px;
        height: 18px;
        // margin: 7px 76px 5px 77px;
        margin: 18px 77px 5px;
      }
      .icon-coffee--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-capsules {
        width: 49px;
        height: 14px;
        // margin: 8px 72px 8px 75px;
        margin: 19px 74px 8px;
      }
      .icon-capsules--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-mousse {
        width: 25px;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 13px 86px 4px;
      }
      .icon-mousse--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-machines {
        width: 15px;
        height: 26px;
        margin: 11px 91px 4px;
      }
      .icon-machines--white {
        display: none;
      }
  
      .text-sticky {
        font-size: 12px;
        min-height: 16px;
        font-family: "NespressoLucas-SemiBd";
        margin: 0 0 9px 0;
        line-height: 1.33;
        letter-spacing: 0.34px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: $brown;
      }

        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }

    }
}
```

```html
...
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="coffee-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-coffee icon-coffee--grey" src="assets/icon-coffee-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-coffee icon-coffee--white" src="assets/icon-coffee-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les cafés</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="capsules-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-capsules icon-capsules--grey" src="assets/icon-capsules-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-capsules icon-capsules--white" src="assets/icon-capsules-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les capsules</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="mousse-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-mousse icon-mousse--grey" src="assets/icon-mousse-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-mousse icon-mousse--white" src="assets/icon-mousse-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les technologies</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="machines-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-machines icon-machines--grey" src="assets/icon-machines-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-machines icon-machines--white" src="assets/icon-machines-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les machines</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `rectangle[el]` to be? It hasn't been defined anywhere in the code you've shown. Also, why are there so many `<a>` elements without `href` attributes? Since they don't do anything without said attribute you may as well use any other element.

Comment: The popup for the `class` tag specifically says not to be used for *css* classes

Comment: `rectangle[el]` doesn't make sense, at all.

Comment: I'm a beginner in coding so I was trying to test some things and I might have a couple mistakes in my code. The reason why I added rectangle[el] is because I was trying to refer to that specific rectangle that comes from the .menu-container that is being clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery the next should work. ✌️

Specific code:

```js
$('.menu-container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

We check what element has been clicked with the click function. The `$(this)` refers to that specific element that has been clicked. Then we gonna look for the class hidden, `.find('.hidden')` and remove it.

**Run code snippet:**

```js
$('.menu-container').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 0 287px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  background-color: $light--black;
  // align-items: center;
  // align-items: stretch;
  


  .menu-container {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;


      &:hover {
        .text-sticky {
          color: white;
        }
        .icon-coffee--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-coffee--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-capsules--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-capsules--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-mousse--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-mousse--white {
          display: block;
        }
        .icon-machines--grey {
          display: none;
        }
        .icon-machines--white {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      @include between(1, 3) {
        position: relative;
        &::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          width: 0.5px;
          right: -3px;
          min-height: 41px;
          background-color: $white;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
      }

      .icon-coffee {
        width: 44px;
        height: 18px;
        // margin: 7px 76px 5px 77px;
        margin: 18px 77px 5px;
      }
      .icon-coffee--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-capsules {
        width: 49px;
        height: 14px;
        // margin: 8px 72px 8px 75px;
        margin: 19px 74px 8px;
      }
      .icon-capsules--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-mousse {
        width: 25px;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 13px 86px 4px;
      }
      .icon-mousse--white {
          display: none;
      }
      .icon-machines {
        width: 15px;
        height: 26px;
        margin: 11px 91px 4px;
      }
      .icon-machines--white {
        display: none;
      }
  
      .text-sticky {
        font-size: 12px;
        min-height: 16px;
        font-family: "NespressoLucas-SemiBd";
        margin: 0 0 9px 0;
        line-height: 1.33;
        letter-spacing: 0.34px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: $brown;
      }

        .hidden {
          display: none;
        }

    }
}
.hidden {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="coffee-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-coffee icon-coffee--grey" src="assets/icon-coffee-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-coffee icon-coffee--white" src="assets/icon-coffee-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les cafés</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="capsules-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-capsules icon-capsules--grey" src="assets/icon-capsules-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-capsules icon-capsules--white" src="assets/icon-capsules-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les capsules</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="mousse-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-mousse icon-mousse--grey" src="assets/icon-mousse-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-mousse icon-mousse--white" src="assets/icon-mousse-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les technologies</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <a class="machines-icon" href="">
          <img class="icon-machines icon-machines--grey" src="assets/icon-machines-grey.svg" alt="">
          <img class="icon-machines icon-machines--white" src="assets/icon-machines-white.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <p class="text-sticky">les machines</p>
        <div class="rectangle hidden">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Your solution is so much simpler and cleaner. However, when I test it the div .menu-container is only active when the .sticky text is clicked. Also, only one .menu-container should be active when clicked. I think it's probably a mistake somewhere else in my code. I uploaded the demo video on a hosting platform for you to see if you want: https://www.veed.io/view/76d6fc74-a545-4401-b4be-37669fde3bc1?sharingWidget=true